# Result image not showing in VSCode

Tags: python, data-visualization, visual-studio-code

Im trying to visualize the data using python in VSCode, the code is down below

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train_df = pd.read_csv('D:/GBM project/train_labels.csv')
plt.figure(figsize = (5, 5))
sns.countplot(data = train_df, x = 'MGMT_value')
```

This code run successfully but no image is shown, could someone tells me where's the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's closing after running successfully. If you're not getting any exceptions after code execution, try following things

1. add `temp=input()` at the end of the program
2. add `plt.show()` at the end of the program
3. add `sns.set_theme()` before last line